# Question on Riemann Lebesgue lemma

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, fourier-series

Suppose $f:[-\pi,\pi]\to \mathbb{C}$ is a function such that $f\in L^1$, ie $f$ is Lebesgue measurable and $$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}|f(x)|dx<+\infty.$$

By the Riemann Lebesgue Lemma we know that if we set $$c_k=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)e^{-ikx}dx,$$ for every integer $k\in\mathbb{Z}$, then $$\lim_{|k|\to+\infty}c_k=0,$$
ie for every $\epsilon>0$ there exist $N=N(\epsilon)\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for every $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ with $|k|>N$ one has $|c_k|<\epsilon$.

Now comes my (probably stupid) question.

Is there a way to conclude, as an "easy consequence" of the integral version of the Riemann Lebesgue lemma stated above, that the same holds even if $k$ is not restricted to integral values? (ie $k \in \mathbb{R}$).

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: The proof here does not claim anything about integer $k$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Lebesgue_lemma

Comment: Yep. Just saw It. I would like to understand wheter Is possible to simply prove It  knowing that the "integer version" of Riemann Lebesgue Lemma holds. I will modify my question.

Comment: I think you can first extend to rational $k$ by an appropriate substitution and then conclude the general case by dominated convergence.

Comment: The problem with this sort of question is that the answer is always "yes": Start with (indicated starting result), then (just do everything in known proof), and voila! a proof from (indicated starting result). The theorem is true, so you can always prove it Proving it "from something" is not a well-defined concept.